# LARAVEL - Retrieve fields from parent table through Foreign Key on child table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm having some trouble trying to retrieve data from parent travel through a foreign key.

I've defined the next One-To-Many relationship on my two models:

[Defining the inverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1en3.png)

[Defining the relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2hrb.png)

I believe I've made no errors on these. I've been following Laravel Documentation so far.

My tables are as follow:

Category table
[
 id INT PK | category_name NVARCHAR(255)
]

Dessert table
[ id INT PK | 
 dessert_name NVARCHAR(255) | description TEXT | id_type INT FK | price DECIMAL(6, 4)
]

[Query and returning a view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mheQS.png)

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWlNZ.png)

Everything works, except for `{{$row->id_type->category_name}}`. If I delete what's after `id_type`, it works. Nevertheless, it only displays the INT type data; and I want the name to be displayed.

This is the thrown exception:

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   Trying to get property of non-object

I've been searching for similar questions, but nothing works for me.
Could it be that I am mistaken somewhere? I'd greatly appreciate for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing that error because the category_name is not set for that relationship. If the id is being returned without the category name when you do $row->id_type by itself, then the category name is missing. I'd look into your database and see what the table itself looks like. Check your $fillable field on your model as well, it could be that when you create a record it is not saving the category_name.